# Complement of a point in $ S^n $ is homeomorphic to $ \mathbb{R}^n $

Tags: general-topology

Define $ S^n $ to be all the $ (n + 1) $-tuples in $ \mathbb{R}^{n + 1} $ whose Euclidean distance to the origin equal $ 1 $. 
I read in [here](https://www3.nd.edu/~stolz/2015F_Math60330/exams/exam_1_solutions.pdf) that the complement of a point in $ S^2 $ is homeomorphic to $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ via the stereographic projection.
Does this hold for every $ n \geq 2 $, i.e. the complement of a point, say $ (0, 0, \dots, 0, 1) $, is homeomorphic to $ \mathbb{R}^n $?
I am having trouble finding an explicit homeomorphism here.
Also if $ U $ and $ V $ are complement of a point such that $ S^n \subseteq U \cup V $, then is $ U \cap V $ homeomorphic to $ S^n $?

Comment: Yes, the first bit is true.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I am having trouble finding an explicit homeomorphism from $ S^n - (, 0, \dots, 0, 1) $ to $ \mathbb{R}^n $.

Comment: Embed the sphere with south pole at the origin and north pole at $(0,0, \ldots, 2)$, which we'll remove.  Now draw the line from the north pole, through a given point $x$ on the sphere.  Write out this line using techniques for writing out lines in $n+1$-dim space.  Next, find out where this line crosses the (hyper)plane defined by $x_{n+1}=0$ by doing the algebra.  This will be $f(x)$.  Note that the formula for $f(x)$ is clearly continuous, so all is good.

Comment: Consider the sphere. Fix the point you are eliminating - say the north pole. Think of the plane as passing through the equator. Fix a point in the plane. Now join the north pole and the fixed point by a line. It intersects the sphere at exactly one point. This gives you the desired map.

Comment: You may want to look [Lee's ITM example 3.6](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=AdIRBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: @puremathonly You can find the explicit construction of higher dimensional stereographic projection here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection#Generalizations